# Fast switching bluetooth Sony headphones between Mac and iPhone, One touch NFC

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

Sony WH-1000MX3 unlike some other headphones can't connect to two devices at the same time.

I like to stay connected to my Macbook pro, but would like to receive a call on my iphone, when I get a call.

Is there a way to quickly switch the bluetooth connection to iPhone?
I thought Sony one touch NFC makes it easy to quickly connect to iPhone, in this case when I am receiving the call.
Were anyone able to get such fast switching working with iPhone and any headphones?

Edit:
 I am open to workarounds.

Comment: This is not possible as Sony states it can't be done with these headphones.  If you're open to workarounds or 3rd party software, [edit] your question to add those option; maybe someone knows more about it.

Comment: @fsb Thanks, added the edit, for workarounds.

Comment: I have a pair of WH-H900N and often need to switch between my Mac and iPhone.  I have to disconnect from one device to switch to the other.  It drives me crazy!

Comment: 'Fast' switching with the WH-1000MX3 now works between iPhone and Apple Watch (at least since series 6 / watchOS 7). You just select the device for playback and will automatically release the bluetooth connection on the iPhone and pick it up on the watch, or vice versa. It doesn't use NFC. But not between those and macOS. Needs to be paired with all of those of course.

Comment: If you're just listening to music Spotify is a pretty good workaround. Just stay connected to your iPhone over bluetooth. You can change songs on your mac and still take phone calls. If you need it for anything else you'll have to get a pair of Apple headphones/earphones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm exactly in the same situation and was very frustrated by it as well.
I haven't yet found a perfect solution, but here are three things I use to make it suck less:

1. Link your iPhone with you Mac Message and FaceTime, allowing you to take calls on your computer-connect headset when you get a call on your phone.(iPhone only :/)
2. Install [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) and the [Bluetooth manager workflow](https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/13493-bluetooth-manager-connect-and-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-easily/) (by Boris Muñoz) This will allow to connect and to disconnect your headset very quickly.
3. Set [this shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469955/setting-shortcuts-to-a-bluetooth-device-in-ios) on your phone (once again, iPhone only) to allow one tap connection.
4. I also was annoyed that sometime my headset would stay connected to my Mac after I closed it and packed away, forcing me to open everything again, so last tip: install [ControlPlane](http:///www.controlplaneapp.com) that allows you to shut down Bluetooth when you close the lid and start it back up when you open it. This article provides a [step-by-step tutorial](https://medium.com/mycostech/controlplane-first-flight-69ba7e6dcfce) to do so.

Here's my 2 cents.

Comment: Seems like https://www.controlplaneapp.com/ is down and the project is looking for a maintainer https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane